# Acute triangle in regular polygon

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

A regular 2015-gon is partitioned into triangles by a set of non-intersecting diagonals.

Prove that among those triangles only one is acute-angled.

Comment: How can triangles be created by non intersecting diagonal?

Comment: An example of this could be: From an arbitrary vertex, you draw lines to other vertices. This action creates triangles with non - intersecting diagonals. We are not talking about the intersection at the vertex, of course.

Comment: I mistook  diagonals as only lines connecting opposite verices:)